# twitter api stream user's home timeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, twitter

I am trying to `stream` user's home timeline as I did with his public tweets.

```
export const streamTweets = async function (T: any, socket: any, feed_type: string) {
try {       
    if(feed_type == 'user_timeline') {
        const stream: any = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow:'1160506639046324444' }); //GTQ twitter a/c ID
        stream.on('tweet', function (tweet: any) {
            let tweetObject = getTweetObject(tweet)
            socket.emit('get tweets', tweetObject);
        }); 

        stream.on('error', (error: any) => {
            throw Error(error);
        });
    } else if(feed_type == 'home_timeline') {
        // const tweets = await T.get('statuses/home_timeline', { count: 10 });
        // let tweetObject = getTweetObject(tweets.data[0])
        // socket.emit('home feed', tweetObject)

        const stream: any = T.stream('statuses/home_timeline'); //PIQ twitter a/c ID
        stream.on('tweet', function (tweet: any) {
            let tweetObject = getTweetObject(tweet)
            socket.emit('home feed', tweetObject);
        });
    }
    
} catch (error) {
    // log errors here..
    throw Error(error)
}
```

}

I get this error:

```
  var err = new Error()
        ^
Error: Bad Twitter streaming request: 404
```

which is obvious.

How can I stream user's home timeline?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Twitter API support for streaming a user’s home timeline.

Comment: Did this not exist when API v2 was first introduced?

Comment: no - home timeline support was released in mid-2022 (after the v2 API was introduced); there's no streaming support for timelines, the example in this question uses the v1.1 statuses/filter endpoint which is a generalised streaming search API, not a timeline endpoint.

Comment: With API v1, I was using `tweepy.streaming.StreamListener` to ingest all the tweets of the accounts I followed but this was discontinued. I was sure there was a replacement...

Comment: From my old code

`from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.userstream()`

I was sure there was a version 2 equivalent

Comment: Ah right - userStream was removed several years ago from v1.1 (~2018 I think); no similar function in v2, you would need to have a stream that searched for Tweets from all the accounts followed by the signed in user.

Comment: I had some doubts about a userStream replacement anyway, since on web or Twitter app, it looks like we don't see all the Tweets of all our follows. So best is to read each followed user's latest one-by-one and process that. Obviously, that wouldn't work for a real-time stream experience.